# Using overflow-y: hidden or overflow-x: hidden to only hide one side of an element

Tags: css, overflow

The title pretty much asks the question but I know using `overflow-y: hidden` and `overflow-x: hidden` you can hide either the top and bottom or the left and ride side of an element  but is there a way to only hide one side using these selectors.

**In particular I am interested in hiding the bottom of a div that is overflowing but not the top.**

If not is there any other CSS only way to accomplish this desired effect?

There is a legitimate purpose for needing this and I'd like to see if there is a standard way of doing this.

To explain slightly, I am only in control of the CSS for a slideshow and I need to push an element inside the slideshow `div` up above the `div` however the `overflow: hidden` values are cutting off this pushed up `div` when I do this. I can remove the `overflow: hidden` completely of course but then that doesn't make for a very good slideshow!

A fiddle is included below:

https://jsfiddle.net/ejhyz7t3/

Comment: Please write a fiddle to demonstrate what you are trying to do.

Comment: Make sure the content doesn't start above the top of the `div`?

Comment: Hi Mark Parnell. I wish it were so easy but it is something I am only in control of the CSS for and I need to push an element inside the div up above the div however the overflow: hidden values are cutting this off when I do it.

Comment: Maybe you could draw a simple graphic showing what you want to achieve!?

Comment: What slide show are you using? off-the-shelf or custom-in-house?

Comment: I believe it is something similar to **[this jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pdx8P/)**. I cannot get it to not crop after the overflow-y is applied either.

Comment: Hi Travis, in essence yes. It would need to hide overflow for the bottom of the table but not the top. It would in theory be something like `overflow-y: hidden, visible;`. However, this obviously doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below jsfiddle based on the example in the question provides the desired effect of cutting off only the bottom edge using `clip`:

https://jsfiddle.net/ejhyz7t3/2/

The full code is copied below for reference:

**HTML**

```
<div class="outer-container">
   <div class="inner-container">
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.outer-container {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.inner-container {
  background: green;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  transform: translateY(-50px);
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0, 100px, 150px, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where I had a draggable div that I wanted to overflow to the right/down, but not top/left.  I solved it by adjusting the z-index.  The container div to z-index:0px; the draggable to z-index:500px; and the divs in the top and left (menus) to z-index:1000px;.  This effectively sandwiched the draggable layer allowing to overflow in the directions I wanted.

Comment: z-index is not to be given in px

Answer (score 0):

Using `clip-path` worked for me. `clip` seems to be deprecated.

Hide only bottom:

```
element.style {
    clip-path: polygon(0 -100%, 100% -100%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.mydiv {  
    clip: rect(-100px, -100px, auto, -100px);  
}
```

Setting the bottom part of the clip rect to `auto` clips like `overflow: hidden` would have.
The `-100px` values are arbitrarily chosen to leave some room for overflowing.